# Django: access the model meta class value

Tags: python, django, inheritance, model-view-controller, model

I have some model classes defined:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class ModelB(ModelA):
    class Meta:
        abstract = False
```

So, now I have a class object, I want to check if it is abstract, is there any way to do this?

For example, I want something like:

```
>>> ModelA.abstract
True
>>> ModelB.abstract
False
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oh, I found that it is easy to get the Meta class by `_meta` field of the class:

```
>>> ModelA._meta.abstract
True
```

Answer (score 1):

technically, strictly speaking, no external method should access a method or property that begins with an underscore (_) as it is private and protected from outsider access. To solve this, in your model file, add a property:

```
class Foo(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Foolish"

    @property
    def verbose_name(self):
        return self._meta.verbose_name
```

Then your view can "properly" access the Meta.verbose_name via Foo().verbose_name as opposed to Foo._meta.verbose_name